# how to read a xlsx stream file using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to read a streamed xlsx file. The user inputs the data via user interface and then the data is passed to me via streaming in xlsx. How do i read it ? I couldn't find any documentation.

cat text.xlsx | python myprogram.py

How do i read this stream ? Any help would be appreciated. I am not sure whether openpyxl allows this read. I am using python3

Answer (score 6):

`openpyxl.load_workbook`'s first argument `filename` can be not only a filename, but also a file-like object, and [`sys.stdin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin) is the file-like object representing your program's stdin.

You need it in binary mode though, see the note in the docs regarding binary standard streams.

```
import sys
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(sys.stdin.buffer)
print(wb.sheetnames)
```

Run:

```
$ cat test.xlsx | python test.py
['Sheet1', 'Sheet2']
```

Comment: I am getting the following error:

    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

Comment: @KumarGovind Are you sure that's XLSX and not XLS? Can you maybe upload a sample file somewhere. You can also try `file test.xlsx` in console: it should recognise the type as "Microsoft OOXML" or something along these lines.

Comment: it is certainly a xlsx file.

Comment: @KumarGovind I cannot reproduce the error. XLSX is a zip file, so it is rather odd that openpyxl is telling you it isn't.

Comment: If you stream files as bytes from a blobstorage e.g. make sure to put the bytes into a bytebuffer first.

Comment: Here's the link to the docs: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.reader.excel.html#openpyxl.reader.excel.load_workbook

Comment: @KumarGovind I realize this is 6 years too late, but you will get the BadZipFile error if the Excel doc is password-protected. You need to will need to use msoffcrypto to decrypt it.

Answer (score 3):

I do not have enough rep to comment, therefore I am posting this as an answer.

As @CheradenineZK mentions, if the input is coming from an (Azure) blob storage, it needs to be wrapped in a byte buffer. I was struggling to figure out exactly how to do this...

```python
import io
import openpyxl

bytes_in = io.BytesIO(myblob.read())
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(bytes_in)
```

is doing the trick for me.