# Python unable to read excel file using openpyxl received from API call as FileStorage

Tags: python, openpyxl

We are trying to read excel file coming within a request into python script from Angular web app.

We read the file as follows:

```
if 'sfile' in req.files:
    sfile = (req.files['sfile'].read())
```

We need to pass `sfile` into another function to read it with openpyxl and do some transformations:

```
readTest = openpyxl.load_workbook(open(sub_odk))
```

The following error is occuring:

> 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 14-15: invalid
> continuation byte

We made sure that the file is strictly with a format of `.xlsx`.

Then we tried with adding `rb` and a similar error occured:

> 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 14-15: invalid
> continuation byte

We tried reading the file as BytesIO as mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194667/how-to-read-a-xlsx-stream-file-using-openpyxl):

```
sfile = io.BytesIO(req.files['sfile'].read())
```

And we got this error:

> expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not BytesIO

Then, we tried with the following:

```
openpyxl.load_workbook(req.files['sfile'].read())
```

and got this error:

> openpyxl does not support
> b'.relspk\x05\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x19\x00\x19\x00\xb3\x06\x00\x00\xeem\x00\x00\x00\x00'
> file format, please check you can open it with Excel first. Supported
> formats are:  .xlsx,.xlsm,.xltx,.xltm

the file type itself is `FileStorage` coming from the API request.

How to read excel files using openpyxl that are coming from a request in python?

Comment: Can you try `openpyxl.load_workbook(req.files['sfile'].read())`?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM the following error occurred, will update the post with it also:
`error openpyxl does not support b'.relspk\x05\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x19\x00\x19\x00\xb3\x06\x00\x00\xeem\x00\x00\x00\x00' file format, please check you can open it with Excel first. Supported formats are: 
.xlsx,.xlsm,.xltx,.xltm`

Comment: Use a file object.

Comment: @CharlieClark can you elaborate on that? what do you mean with file object?